# Automatically growing lists as in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to add elements to a list at positions outside the current list's length? Something equivalent to the following MATLAB code snippet:

```
x = [1,2,3];
x(5) = 5
```

which returns:

```
x =

     1     2     3     0     5
```

Comment: Sorry if the following is obvious to you (also, it's a bit off-topic): This is bad practice in MATLAB and in a direct translation also in Mathematica, as in this way new memory needs to be allocated every time you add an element and this takes a lot of time. Better preallocate by `x=zeros(1,n)`. (Of course this doesn't matter much if you do it only once in the whole program.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
test = {1, 2, 3}

addEm[list_, position_, ele_] := 
 Module[{tmp = Join[list, ConstantArray[0, position - Length@list]]}, 
  tmp[[position]] = ele; tmp]

addEm[test, 6, 55]

(* {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 55} *)
```

You'll probably want to add sanity checks...

Comment: It's neater to use `PadRight`.

Comment: Thank you both! I thought there was a native way to do it but I was wrong!

Answer (score 7):

why not simply:

```
x2[n_, a_] := PadRight[x, n, 0] + (SparseArray[n -> a] // Normal)

x2[10,5]

(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

More for my own personal edification and possible enlightenment from more experienced users, here are two other possibilities.  First, Use a sparse array with a size much larger than expected.

```
a = Range@3;
b = SparseArray[a, 10^7];
```

It results in a bit of overhead

```
ByteCount /@ {a, b}
(* {128, 720} *)
```

Which decreases with increasing (initial) array size

```
Table[With[{a = Range@x, b = SparseArray[Range@x, 10^7]}, {x, 
ByteCount[b]/ByteCount[a]}], {x, 5, 1000, 5}] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Assign away

```
b[[5]] = 5
(* 5 *)
```

Normal will return an array of Length defined in the Sparse Array

```
Length[Normal[b]]
(* 10000000 *)
```

Create a "normal" array without padding using `ArrayRules`

```
ArrayRules[b]
(* {{1} -> 1, {2} -> 2, {3} -> 3, {5} -> 5, {_} -> 0} *)
Normal@b[[1 ;; First@First@Last@Most@Sort@ArrayRules[b]]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 0, 5} *)
```

Second, with v10, we can emulate this behavior with Associations.  This is food for thought, and I haven't thought much about it yet.

```
c = Association@ MapIndexed[First@#2 -> #1 &, {1, 2, 3}]
(* <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3|> *)
```

Add an element with `AppendTo`

```
AppendTo[c, 5 -> 5]
(* <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 5 -> 5|> *)
```

Note that single brackets are used in Key/Value associations

```
c[5]
(* 5 *)
```

The problem (feature?) here is that missing elements are indicated as such

```
c[4]
(* Missing["KeyAbsent", 4] *)
```

Convert to an array when you are done "messing" with the elements

```
SparseArray[Normal[c]] // Normal
(* {1, 2, 3, 0, 5} *)
```

Comment: +1. Turns out you can use `Lookup` with a default value. e.g.: `Lookup[c, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 0]`

Answer (score 3):

Playing with UpValues:

```
Unprotect@Part;
Part/:Set[Part[list_,part_],value_]:=
    list=MapAt[value&,If[Length@list<part,PadRight[list,part],list],part]
Protect@Part;
```

Now you can do:

```
l = {1, 2, 3, 4};
l[[10]] = "x"
```

and get:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "xx"}
```

**Important: I do not recommend to Unprotect system symbols.**